# Rounded Rectangle tool and proportional corner radius in Photoshop

Tags: adobe, photoshop

When using the Rounded Rectangle Tool in Photoshop you can can set the corner radius.

However, is there any way to lock in a corner radius so that a rounded corner will look the same proportionally on a big rectangle or a small rectangle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible way I know to keep a fixed size-to-roundedness ratio is to create one vector element with the desired ratio and then duplicate and resize it.